# Enqueued stylesheets only loading when logged in. Hosting cache?

Tags: cache, hosting

I'm having an issue where all my enqueued stylesheets in functions.php are only loading and showing in the head when I'm logged into wp-admin. When not logged in (i.e. what everyone sees), the stylesheets do not appear in the head. This happened the other day after changing some CSS classes, and everything was broken. I assumed it was just the hosting cache and after like 12 hours it resolved itself and the stylesheets appeared again.

I made some more changes now 2 days ago, the same thing happened where the navbar is completely broken because of some refactoring I had to do, yet it hasn't resolved itself this time, and it's nearly been 48 hours.

I deleted the contents of the cache folder in wp-content, but the issue still persists. What could be causing this? The enqueued scripts in the same function are loading and showing properly -- it's just the stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, maybe I jumped the gun. 30 minutes after I cleared the cache folder the site appears to be loading properly now. I assumed it would resolve immediately, but I guess not.